# Mavproxy + mission planner + dronekit with no companion computer

Tags: python, dronekit

I’m trying to connect mavproxy, mission planner and dronekit to my hexa.
i am not using a companion computer my setup is as follows:
i have a pc running windows for mission planner and on that same pc im running a virtual machine with ubuntu 16.04 running dronekit and mavproxy.

first I'm running mavproxy and forking out 2 connections, 1 for mission planner and one for dronekit with the following code:

```
mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyUSB0(I'm telling mavproxy to use the serial which the telemetry dongle is connected to) --baudrate=57600 --out=127.0.0.1:14551(ip address on my virtual ubuntu) --out=10.0.0.7:14550 (IP for my windows machine)
```

I am able to connect to the drone in mission planner via the UDP at port 14550. and I am able to send commands via mavproxy console such as change modes/arm etc.

my problem is when I execute my connect script from dronekit to connect to the drone I'm getting a timeout error.

the code

```
from dronekit import connect, VehicleMode, LocationGlobalRelative

import time

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = ‘commands’)

parser.add_argument(’–connect’)

args =parser.parse_args()

connection_string = args.connect

vehicle = connect(connection_string ,wait_ready=True)
```

when I open a new terminal I run the command to launch and connect drone kit

```
python connect.py --connect 127.0.0.1:14551
```

once I run this it gets stuck and after 30 seconds I get the following output:

```
dronekit.TimeoutError: wait_ready experienced a timeout after 30 seconds.
```

sometimes I get the following output:

```
gcs failsafe cleared
```

and then it gets stuck and after 30 seconds:

```
dronekit.APIException: Timeout in initializing connection.
```

I searched for about 3 days for solutions and tried everything that is out there pretty much, such as telling dronekit to wait longer than 30 seconds, but still, I get the same error.
I updated dronekit to the latest version, updated pymavlink and pyserial. also downgraded them to check if it will solve this but nothing works.

**my main question is: is this error happening because dronekit can only run on a companion computer? and is not built for connecting threw telemetry radio?
if not, what am I doing wrong?**

I sincerely am lost and praying that someone can help me.
thanks in advance. I would literally pay someone for a solution.

and again, sorry for the double post.

Comment: you have a typo on this line `parser.add_argument(’–connect’)`; it should be `parser.add_argument('--connect')`. I'm not sure that'll fix your issue though. And I don't know how your keyboard is set up but you should be using single or double **straight** quotes so `description = ‘commands’` should be `description = 'commands'`